# Associating revisions with a Redmine issue

Tags: commit, redmine, revision

Is there a way to manually associate a revision/commit with a Redmine issue?

Normally we do that by having a proper format of the commit message ("Resolves #..." in our case). But I forgot about it and used a different message.

I have no rights to change the commit message now. And even if I would I still would not be able to delete Redmine's data for it to rebuild it again. (Method given in question [Redmine and SVN: How to link a Revision to an Issue AFTER the commit has happened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047906/redmine-and-svn-how-to-link-a-revision-to-an-issue-after-the-commit-has-happene)).

I have updated the issue with "r..." comment which properly linked to the revision. But that is just a link. It didn't generate the "Associating revisions" as a proper commit message would.

Is there any way to manually force Redmine to see such an association?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an easy way to manually associate Redmine issue with a commit. In your project, click the Repository tab, choose target revision, click the Add link on the right side and choose the target issue. Now you have this revision associated with your issue.

Notice that you can also delete associations here.

For both operations, it is necessary to have "Manage related issues" permission.

This works for Redmine version 2.4.2.

Comment: Could it be dependent on administration settings? I don't see any such add link on the revision page. Yet if revision is associated with some issues it does show "Related issues" header and a corresponding list.

Comment: @AdamBadura you need to have "Manage related issues" permission, I've edited the answer.

Comment: @Michal Is there any to do this with redmine 4.2?